# How do you return a mediawiki installation back to the "just installed" state?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to take a working, stable, MediaWiki directory under /var/www, copy its contents to a new directory, and perform whatever steps are necessary to place the new directory into "just installed" state.

Media Wiki 1.15.0
Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at localhost Port 80
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2010 16:08:24)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.7 (Tikanga)
Your MySQL connection id is 487
Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution

I am familiar enough with MySQL and the config files to change whatever is needed to reset everything. I cannot find any instructions like this at all out on the web.

Comment: Why not just do a fresh install of the same version to the new location?

Comment: Probably as simple as cleaning the database and removing the generated config file. What will doing this accomplish vs. downloading the tarball and extracting it?

Comment: Where can I get that version? I'd do it in a second. Also, if you'd answer this, I'd mark it as an answer, and vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just download a new Media Wiki install here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download

Then just unzip it and go. I don't understand the need for moving an old one if you don't want any of the data on it.

Comment: As it turns out, in the MediaWiki's top directory mv LocalSettings.php LocalSettings.php.old did the trick.